# How to fix the “divide by zero” error in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my query is :

```
Select sum (node.weight * ans.cn_age) / sum (node.weight) as sum_weight , poll.pollName as poll , poll.endDate as date 
From  report.cm_job_satisfaction ans 
Join poll_management.POLLES poll on ans.cn_pollid = poll.id 
Join poll_management.POSITIONS node on ans.cn_positionid = node.id  
Group by poll , date 
Order by date
```

but i have error :

```
ERROR:  division by zero
********** Error **********

ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

I know because some node.weight is 0 however how to fix this ?

Comment: change `sum (node.weight * ans.cn_age) / sum (node.weight) as sum_weight` to `sum (node.weight * ans.cn_age) / greatest(sum (node.weight),0.00000000000000001) as sum_weight` or apply other logic

Comment: Simple, don't divide by 0. Not sure what else to say about that... You could add a `having` clause and filter out sums of 0.

Comment: What should come out when your divisor `sum (node.weight)` is zero?

Comment: Use `null`: `.../ nullif(sum(node.weight), 0)`

Comment: What result would you prefer? Should it return null or zero or 99999 or what when dividing by 0?

Comment: @VaoTsun  and a_horse_with_no_name it's  fixed thank you both of you